# Running cron job/task at every hour

Tags: cron, jobs, schedule, job-scheduling, cron-task

Which one is the correct syntax for running a job at every hour?

`0 0 * * * *`

`0 0 */1 * * *`

Also how are they both different?

Comment: Check out [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/). It can tell you when the different timings run

Comment: @Reyno I did check it out but I wanted to know how are they both different because they are doing the same work for me.

Answer (score 18):

The correct syntax for every hour job is `0 * * * *`.

But you can use both `0 0 * * * *` and `0 0 */1 * * *`
Since `*/1` means every 1 hour/minute/second like the `*`.

Comment: they both are doing the same work for me, running at every hour